# How to open XML file inner code as on browser

Tags: wordpress

I have a mucow format file and have some javascript,xml and html content under the file.Can anybody please tell me how can i see the file output in the browser.

Comment: I have changed it to .xml and .html but it won't work it just shows the code onto the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the file output in a browser, you can try online xml viewer websites like http://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer

If you want to display the output of the xml file in your wordpress site, You can use wordpress plugins  or write your own codes according to the structure.

Loading xml in php is very simple.

```
<?php
   $xml=simplexml_load_file("javascript.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
   print_r($xml);
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the concern,xml viewer shows the inside code only but i need the output of the particular file.

Comment: give me link of the xml file and tell me exactly what you want to see.

Comment: i have it locally on my machine.